# Error OCI8 directorio no existe

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

acudo a ustedes por que estoy un poco desesperado, he cambiado de version php de l 7.0 a la 7.2 y me aparece un problema con la OCI8.

"PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8 (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so (libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.2.33 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2020 10:02:54) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies"

El fichero si existe y tiene permisos de lectura.

Favor su ayuda, tengo usuarios esperando.

Saludos.

Comment: Seguro que existe? el mensaje es muy claro.

Comment: mira esta pregunta en el sitio en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833041/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-oci8-so-php-7-2/47833414